# Prove that $x+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^3}<\sqrt{x^2+1}<x+\frac{1}{2x}$ for all positive real numbers x

Tags: inequality

This is a math problem from the German Math Olympiad, but in this case I do not know where to start, probably because I do not have enough intuition regarding inequalities.

However, I tried to apply the standard AM-GM equation which didn't help, and in general I could not find a good up-/ downward estimation for the root term.
I also looked at the function plots and it seems that those three terms are *very* close to each other which seems to make this problem even more difficult to prove.

Any tips on how to begin? Please do not post a complete solution here.

BTW usually those problems provide an elegant solution based on non-university level knowledge, so I do not like to use an approach like a series expansion of the root term!

EDIT: Alright, the right side should've been obvious:
$$0<\frac{1}{4x^2}\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x^2+1}<\sqrt{x^2+1+\frac{1}{4x^2}}=\sqrt{x^2+2x\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{4x^2}}=x+\frac{1}{2x}$$

EDIT 2: So, I noted that squaring the left inequality (considering $x>0$ as well as $LHS>0$) gives me an inequality equivalent to $x\gt\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}}$.
Therefore, I only have to show that the Assumption $LHS\gt 0$ is implying exactly this.
I thus noted that $0=x+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^3}$ has only one positive solution $\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}}{2}\gt\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}}$ -- but how do I show this as an inequality? I always get very confused about inequations with quadratic polynomials, especially regarding the direction of the inequality sign...

EDIT 3: **Got it!** So, let me state the whole proof ;)

To prove: $L:=x+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^3}<\sqrt{x^2+1}=:R,\quad x>0$

a) Consider $L\leq0$. $x>0$ implies $R>0 \Rightarrow L<R$

b) Consider $L\gt0$. We get 
$$
0<x+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^3} \Rightarrow 0\lt x^4+\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{8} = (x^2)^2 + 2\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{4^2}-\frac{1}{4^2}-\frac{1}{8} = (x^2+\frac{1}{4})^2-\frac{3}{16}\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\lt x^2+\frac{1}{4} \Leftrightarrow x^2 \gt \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{4}
 \Leftrightarrow x \gt \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{4}} \Rightarrow x\gt \sqrt{\frac{1}{8}}
$$

From that, we get 
$$
\frac{1}{8x^2}\lt 1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{8x^2}\frac{1}{8x^4}\lt \frac{1}{8x^4}
\Leftrightarrow (\frac{1}{8x^3})^2-\frac{1}{8x^4}\lt0 \\
\Leftrightarrow x^2+1+(\frac{1}{8x^3})^2-\frac{1}{8x^4}\lt x^2+1
$$

Noticing that $L^2=x^2+1+(\frac{1}{8x^3})^2-\frac{1}{8x^4}$ and $R^2=x^2+1$ gives you
$$
\Leftrightarrow L^2 \lt R^2 \Leftrightarrow L\lt R
$$
*...quod erat demonstrandum.*

Sorry it took so long, I am not used to write that much TeX ;)
BTW, can anyone leave a comment regarding the "beauty" of my proof? I tried to compose this final version as clean as possible!

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+1} < x + \frac{1}{2x}$ can be easily proved by squaring both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A start:** Square everything. The inequality on the right will be obvious. The one on the left is a little more unpleasant.

Comment: You're right, that should've been obvious... brb trying the left side!

Comment: There is useful cancellation on the left when you square. You do have to play around a bit. Roughly speaking for the $x$ that could give trouble after the squaring, the expression on the left is less $1$ (and possibly negative, making the inequality clear).

Comment: So I get $(x+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^3})^2=x^2+1+(\frac{1}{8x^3})^2-\frac{1}{8x^4}$. Thus, I have to prove that $(\frac{1}{8x^3})^2-\frac{1}{8x^4}<0$, right? But I don't get where to get from there, the statement seems quite wrong...

Comment: hmm, just noted that the last inequality is equivalent to $x>\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}}$... can I construct this condition by the previous assumption that the LHS is greater than zero?

Comment: Got the concept, see my edit.

Comment: So you noticed that below $\sqrt{1/8}$ there is no trouble, because the left side is less than $1$. There is need to find roots, fairly crude estimates are good enough.

Comment: Thanks, I could finish it :) hope my approach has been realized correctly

Comment: It is on the awkward side. Typo at the beginning of b), you left out the denominator. Too many fractions, should be able to show much faster that we are OK if $\frac{1}{x}\lt\sqrt{8}$. Then show that if $\frac{1}{x}\ge \sqrt{8}$ the original left side is less than $1$. Lots of slack!

Comment: Where did I leave the denominator? The factor $\frac{1}{x^3}$ could be left because of $x>0\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x^3}>0$

Comment: I called it a "typo." You wrote $x+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^3}=\dots$. Of course you did not mean they are equal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17055/discussion-between-lukas-juhrich-and-andre-nicolas).

Comment: After a couple of unpleasant experiences, I stopped using chat. When writing up contest questions,  one has to be very careful. I have graded Olympiads both national and international (APMO). The grading is quite unforgiving.

Comment: I do not need to care about the grading as I finished school this year. I use these problems as an exercise for myself.
However it is true that I shouldn't state something which is not mathematically correct.
What do you mean by "writing up" those questions? I kind of don't get the relation.

Comment: I was being imprecise, should have said contest solutions. One may have the right idea in a contest question, but if the write-up of the solution is not exact, the grade can drop precipitously from the standard $7$. In your solution, it would have been easier to square $x+\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{1}{8x^3}$ explicitly. The fact that we are OK for $\frac{1}{x}\le \sqrt{8}$ drops out immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Just squaring everything seems the best way:
$$
\left(x+\frac1{2x}\right)^2
=x^2+1+\frac1{4x^2}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\color{#C00000}{x+\frac1{2x}}-\frac1{8x^3}\right)^2
&=\color{#C00000}{x^2+1+\frac1{4x^2}}-\frac2{8x^3}\left(\color{#C00000}{x+\frac1{2x}}\right)+\frac1{64x^6}\\
&=x^2+1-\frac1{8x^4}+\frac1{64x^6}
\end{align}
$$
Now you need to consider what happens to $x+\dfrac1{2x}-\dfrac1{8x^3}$ when $\dfrac1{64x^6}\gt\dfrac1{8x^4}$.

---

Now that the question seems answered, I might as well add the last little bit.

If $8x^2\lt1$, then
$$
\begin{align}
x+\frac1{2x}-\frac1{8x^3}
&=\frac{8x^4+4x^2-1}{8x^3}\\
&\le\frac{x^2+4x^2-1}{8x^3}\\
&\le\frac{\frac58-1}{8x^3}\\
&=-\frac3{64x^3}\\[4pt]
&\lt-\frac3{\sqrt8}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to note that

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{x^2+1}&=x\sqrt{1+\frac 1{x^2}}\\
&=x\left(1+\frac 1{x^2}\right)^{\frac 12}\\
&=x\left[1+\frac12\cdot \frac 1{x^2}+\frac {\frac 12\cdot -\frac 12}{1\cdot 2}\frac1{4x^4}+\cdots \right]\\
&=x+\frac 1{2x}-\frac 1{8x^3}+\cdots \end{align}$$